# how to handle backspace in key up

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a data stored in database (Charles, Dale, Jack, William). I used PHP code to extract data from database, which displays all the data initially. Now I add one textfield where I can write any of the four above names, and on keyup only the name written on textfield gets displayed. But I got a problem when I clear the textfield it does not show anything. I want to show back all the extracted data from database when I clear the textfield.

The given below is my jQuery code.

```
$('#search_data').keyup(function() {
    var search_data = $('#search_data').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'db.php',
        data: {search: search_data},
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(result) {
            $(".container").html(result);
        }
    });
});

<input type="text" id="search_data" class="col-xs-2">
<input type="submit" id="search_button" class="btn-info go inline" value="Search" style="cursor:pointer; position:absolute; ">
```

The given below is my sql code

```
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employee WHERE Employee_name LIKE '%$s%' ");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select everything if the input is empty you can do something like:

```
$sql =  "SELECT * FROM employee";
if (!empty($s)) {
   $sql .= " WHERE Employee_name LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($s)%."'"; 
}

$result2 = mysql_query($sql);
```

A few things to note:

1. `mysql_*` functions were removed in PHP version 7 and should not be used.
2. Your code was (and this example may still be) vulnerable to SQL injections.

You must migrate to using `mysqli_*` functions or `PDO` and prepared statements.